# Database diagrams not displaying after upgrading to SSMS 18.12.1

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2019

I upgraded SSMS this morning to 18.12.1.

After upgrading, when I opened my database diagrams, all of them were displayed as blank pages.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#bug-fixes-in-186), and this sounds similar to your problem (emphasis mine).

> Fixed long outstanding issue with Database Diagrams, causing both the
> corruption of existing diagrams and SSMS to crash. If you **created or
> saved a diagram using SSMS 18.0 through 18.5.1, and that diagram
> includes a Text Annotation**, you won't be able to open that diagram **in
> any version of SSMS**. With this fix, SSMS 18.6 can open and save a
> diagram created by SSMS 17.9.1 and prior. SSMS 17.9.1 and previous
> releases can also open the diagram after being saved by SSMS 18.6.

In the original text, there is a link to a feedback item, but it's dead. The web archive has it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201030204949/https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37992649).

There are other feedback items on [the current feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) indicating problems with diagrams persist for some users well after SSMS 18.6.